# Where to open the -X and -e switch in intellij idea

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

When I use intellij idea to run a elasticsearch , it comes the following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (default) on project elasticsearch: Resources archive cannot be found. Failure to find org.elasticsearch:dev-tools:jar:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT in https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of oss-snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced
```

and give me some tips:

```
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

but I don't know where to using the -e and -X switch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `Run/Debug Configuration` for your maven plugin, and in the field `Command line` you can enter the options. This is an example which is equivalent to the command line call `mvn -e -X clean package` :

[image]